# Azure B2C SigninEvents Graph Api

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to access the sign-in events for my Azure AD B2C tenant via the Graph API, however I keep getting the following error. Is the error occuring because Azure AD B2C does not support retrieving signins for a user via the Graph api?

```
{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "Authentication_ApplicationBasedRequestFromNonPremiumTenant",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en",
      "value": "Application based api auth request from non premium tenant"
    },
    "requestId": "0b16f6cc-8a1f-4f5d-9d57-be8606570eee",
    "date": "2017-11-10 18:29:34Z"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Sign-in and Audit APIs aren't supported in Azure AD B2C yet**. You can request this feature in the [Azure AD B2C feedback forum](https://aka.ms/aadb2c).

The [Azure AD B2C FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs) states:

> ***What reporting and auditing features does Azure AD B2C provide? Are they the same as in Azure AD Premium?***
>
> No, Azure AD B2C does not support the same set of reports as Azure AD Premium. However there are many commonalities:
>
> - The sign-in reports provide a record of each sign-in with reduced details.
> - Audit reports are available in the Azure portal, under Azure Active Directory> ACTIVITY-Audit logs>Choose B2C and apply filters as desired. Both admin activity as well as application activity are covered.
> - A usage report, covering number of users, number of logins, and volume of MFA is available at [Usage Reporting API](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-usage-reporting-api)

Although not super clear, it states that **sign-in and audit reports are available in the portal. The only API available is for [Usage Reporting](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-usage-reporting-api).**

That being said, **you can enable the sign-in and audit reports, but you'd need to get Azure AD Premium for that.** However, as indicated above, it'll won't have the same level of detail as in regular Azure AD.